# Batch file for running NPM if its not on your PATH

Tags: node.js, bash, batch-file, npm

I have a requirement that I cannot add NPM to my PATH variable.  I have a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash 
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias npm-exec='PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH'
npm-exec npm install
npm-exec gulp
```

which runs my tasks and work.  I need to know how to accomplish this same goal in a batch file as well.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can add it to PATH inside the batch file, the change will be temporary. Then just run the commands as usual. You can even explicitly restore PATH later from a variable if you really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've accomplished that by doing the following inside the batch file:

```
SET PATH=%APPDATA%\npm;%PATH%
call npm install
```

The first line just basically prepends the current user's roaming profile path to the PATH.

The second line requires `call` since npm is actually a *.cmd*, and without it your batch file will exit prematurely right after any call to npm.